# How do I make a searchbar in Navbar component so that it renders the search result in other component in react?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have a Navbar component with search input and onchange function.
I have this Navbar inside the home component.
I have this Navbar fixed on top of all pages.
I am trying to figure out how to use this navbar so that it filters data and render it in other component? etc. clothing

````
Navbar component

const Navbar = () => {

  const [search, setSearch] = useState("")

  return (
    <div className='topSection'>
      <div className="topDiv">
        <div className="searchDiv">
          <BiSearch className='small-icon' />
          <input 
          type="text" 
          placeholder='Search' 
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>```




clothing component


```<div className="itemLists">
              {items.length === 0
                ? "No items found"
                :
                items.map((item) =>
                    <div className="itemCard" key={item.id}>
                      <img src={item.img} alt='clothes' />
                      <div className="itemText">
                        <h4>{item.brand}</h4>
                        <p>{item.description}</p>
                        <p>{item.color}</p>
                        <h3><strong>${item.price}</strong></h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}
            </div>```
````

Comment: You can use context here if you want to provide some value (The searched string in your case) down the render tree without passing it to individual components. Check out the context api https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use a redux context to share the search value, and access that state in your clothing component.

```
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
const Navbar = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    dispatch({type: "setSearch", payload: e.target.value});    
  }
  return (
    <div className='topSection'>
      <div className="topDiv">
        <div className="searchDiv">
          <BiSearch className='small-icon' />
          <input 
          type="text" 
          placeholder='Search' 
          onChange={handleClick}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>)
}
```

Your clothing component may look something like this

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
const Clothing = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState();
  const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState([]);
  const search = useSelector(state => state.search);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Retrieve your data
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(items){
      const searchedItems = items.filter(item => item.name.includes(search));
      setFilteredItems(searchedItems);
    }
  }, [items, search])
  return(
    <div className="itemLists">
      {filteredItems.map(item => (
        <div className="itemCard" key={item.id}>
          <img src={item.img} alt='clothes' />
          <div className="itemText">
            <h4>{item.brand}</h4>
            <p>{item.description}</p>
            <p>{item.color}</p>
            <h3><strong>${item.price}</strong></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And to setup redux in your project. Check the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/api/api-reference).
Hope this can help.